# SQL get a list of duplicate groups with a number of occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on what should be a simple query but I can't seem to get the result I desire.

I have a list of people with the following attributes ID, GroupNo, LastName.
Multiple people may be assigned to the same GroupNo and they can have different or the same Last Names. I am only interested in a list of people that have more than one Last Name assigned to the same GroupNo. I also need to know how many occurrences are in each GroupNo / LastName combination.

For example,

```
ID| GroupNo | LastName
1 | 003000 | MURAD
2 | 003000 | MURAD
3 | 003000 | MURAD
4 | 004020 | MAZZA
5 | 004020 | BOOTH
6 | 010930 | ZHANG
7 | 010930 | YAN
8 | 010930 | ZHANG
```

result should be:

```
GroupNo | LastName | Occurences
004020 | MAZZA | 1
004020 | BOOTH | 1
010930 | ZHANG | 2
010930 | YAN | 1
```

I tried to play with OVER(Partition By...) clause but not with much luck.

Any assistance is highly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: @Max . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Joe that doesn't work because the result will include records where the last name is the same for the whole group (first 3 records in my example)

Answer (score 0):

I found your result with this way

```
DECLARE @test AS TABLE(ID INT ,GroupNo VARCHAR(10),LastName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @test
(
ID,
GroupNo,
LastName
)
VALUES(1,'003000','MURAD'),(2,'003000','MURAD'),(3,'003000','MURAD'),(1,'004020','MAZZA'),(1,'004020','BOOTH')
,(1,'010930','ZHANG'),(1,'010930','YAN'),(1,'010930','ZHANG')

SELECT t2.GroupNo,t2.LastName,COUNT(*)AS cnt FROM(
SELECT res.GroupNo , COUNT(*) AS cnt1 FROM(
SELECT t.GroupNo,t.LastName,COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM @test AS t
GROUP BY t.GroupNo , t.LastName) res
GROUP BY res.GroupNo
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) res2
INNER JOIN @test AS t2 ON t2.GroupNo = res2.GroupNo
GROUP BY t2.GroupNo,t2.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just using group by and having to get only the ones that have more than one row:

```
SELECT GroupNo,LastName,COUNT(*) AS Occurences
FROM your_table
GROUP BY GroupNo,LastName
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: groups that have multiple people the same last name will be also be returned which is what i am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using window functions:

```
select groupno, lastname, cnt
from (select groupno, lastname, count(*) as cnt,
             min(lastname) over (partition by groupno) as min_lastname,
             max(lastname) over (partition by groupno) as max_lastname
      from t
      group by groupno, lastname
     ) gl
where min_lastname <> max_lastname
order by groupno, lastname;
```

Here is another way to phrase it, without window functions:

```
select groupno, lastname, count(*) as cnt
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.groupno = t.groupno and t2.lastname <> t.lastname
             )
group by groupno, lastname
order by groupno, lastname;
```

Comment: Result was exactly what I needed!